# Independence of more than 2 random variabels

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, independence

So the initial task is to show that $X, Y$ and $XY$ are pairwise independent but not independent given that $X,Y$ are two independent r.v. on some probability space such that $P_X = P_Y = \frac{1}{2}(\delta_1 + \delta_{-1})$.

I've firstly tried to write down the cdf in a more intuitive way

$$F_X(x) = \begin{cases}
0,x <-1 \\ 
\frac{1}{2}, x \in [-1,1)  \\ 
1, x\ge1
\end{cases}
$$

and the corresponding mass function:

$$f_X(x) = \begin{cases}
0,x \ne \pm1 \\ 
\frac{1}{2}, else  
\end{cases}
$$

and the same for $Y$

But where to go from here...
I realize that we need to construct the same functions for $XY$ and then to work with them but I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: I could be wrong but actually $f_X(x) = 0$ i.e. there is no such mass function?

Comment: Hmmm, I'm confused now... I've constructed it in the following way: $f_X(x) = P(X=x) = \begin{cases}
0,x \ne \pm1 \\ 
\frac{1}{2}, else  
\end{cases}$  So if we consider not an interval but rather a single point $x = \pm1$, we have that one of the Dirac functions is $1$. Do you think it's wrong ?

Comment: I  think first part of comment is wrong and second part of comment is correct. One of the Dirac functions being 1 means the cdf won't be zero but not all cdfs have corresponding PDFs right? Like degenerate distribution or cantor distribution?

Comment: Computing CDFs is useless here. Here is a nudge in the right direction. Consider $Z=XY$ and $(X,Z)$, say. Then $X$ is always $\pm1$ and $Z$ is always $\pm1$ hence $(X,Z)$ is always in the set $$\{(-1,-1),(-1,+1),(+1,-1),(+1,+1)\}=\{-1,+1\}^2$$ Furthermore, $$P(X=+1)=P(X=-1)=P(Z=+1)=P(Z=-1)=\frac12$$ (Can you prove this?) Thus, all that is left to do to prove that $(X,Z)$ is independent is to show that $$P(X=+1,Z=+1)=P(X=+1,Z=-1)=P(X=-1,Z=+1)=P(X=-1,Z=-1)=\frac14$$Can you do that?

Comment: Thanks for your response.  $$P(Z=1) = P(XY=1) = P(X=1, Y=1) + P(X=-1, Y=-1) = P(X=1) P(Y=1) + P(X=-1)P(Y=-1) = \frac14 + \frac14 = \frac12$$.    $$P(X=1,Z=1) = P(X=1|Z=1)P(Z=1) = \frac12 \frac12 = \frac14$$ since given that $XY=1$ there are two pairs $(X,Y)$ that satisfy that condition and $X=1$ only in one of them. Does this approach also work for the part where we have to disprove independence (not in the pairwise sense) ?

Comment: I think I got it now. $$P(X=1,Y=1,Z=1) = P(X=1, Y=1|Z=1)P(Z=1) = \frac12 \frac12 = \frac14$$ again by the fact that if $Z=XY=1$ we have 2 pairs $(-1,-1)$ and $(1,1)$ that satisfy the condition so the probability is $\frac12$.  But the product of all 3 probabilities will be $\frac18$ and that shows dependence.

Comment: Indeed, or simply $$P(X=1,Y=1,Z=-1)=0$$